# Timer stops in Windows Service

Tags: .net, windows, c#-4.0, service, timer

I have a `Windows Service` and a `System.Timers.Timer` inside it. The timer's `AutoReset` property is set to `false`, and the code which is inside `Elapsed` `event` of the timer is wrapped in such a `try..catch..finally` block:

```
try
{
    Parallel.ForEach (...) 
        {
            DoSomeAction();
        }
}
catch
{
    LogException(...);
}
finally
{
    // _timer is the System.Timers.Timer
    _timer.Start();
}
```

`DoSomeAction()` method also runs some concurrent operations through Task.Run method.

I understand that .NET's timer swallows the exceptions however since the entire code is wrapped in a try...catch...finally block I expect that once an exception is raised, the finally block restart the timer again but it does not happen. As a result we have to constantly watch this Windows service and re-start it a few times a day!

My guess is that an exception happens in one of the threads but then the try..catch block is unable to capture it?

Comment: Instead of fixing the symptom by restarting the timer, fix the exception. At least catch and log it in the timer handler.

Comment: Is your function `LogException(...)` getting called at all ?

Comment: We log all exceptions in all threads. No exception is seen in the logs!  I am not sure if the code inside the catch block is called.

Comment: You are going to have to consult a psychic.  Add more logging, not just exceptions.

Comment: Are you aware that a finally outside of Task.Run does not get control when the task ends?

Comment: Parallel.Foreach makes current thread waits for all concurrent threads to finish. I use Task.WaitAll to make sure all other tasks finish as well. Therefore I expect the control to be taken by finally block. Is this not correct?!